# Mood: countable or uncountable

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

Some dictionaries, such as [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mood), show that `mood` is a countable noun.

> The drink had put him in an amiable mood.

Other dictionaries, such as [Macmillan dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/mood), show that `mood` can be either countable or uncountable.

So, is there any difference in terms of meaning/usage when `mood` is used as a countable or uncountable noun?

For example, the following is from [style: purdue.edu](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/writing_style/style%20/context.html):

> Style allows writers to create mood and evoke feeling in readers.

As we can see, `mood` here is used as an uncountable noun.

Comment: You're looking at this backwards. Mood has several meanings - as well as meaning the emotional state of an individual or the shared attitude of a group, it can refer to a grammatical property or a literary property (as in your last example sentence). In some of these meanings it is usually countable, while in others it can be uncountable. Are you interested in a particular meaning of mood?

Comment: To put it another way, is it grammatically correct to say "Style allows writers to create moods and evoke feeling in readers."? If not, then why.

Comment: The question you should ask is "Is it idiomatic English?" I would say that the plural is less idiomatic, because one meaning of _mood_ is 'An angry, irritable or sullen state of mind' (Oxford), and the plural sounds as though the writer is putting their readers in a _bad_ mood.

Comment: It isn't wrong to say "Style allows writers to create moods," but you are not going from one apple to two when you add the plural. Creating *mood* means being able to give the reader *any* sense of tension, humor, or calm.

Comment: *Mood* is singular, *moods* is plural and, as such, may be countable depending on context and usage.  That moods are *subtizable* but may not be *countable* would be a different interpretation. Then there's the issue of what is *countable*. If one means *quantifiable* then that has a mathematically countable or a qualitatively estimable, approximating meaning, again depending on context and usage.

Answer (score 2):

*Almost* all English nouns can be used both as countable and uncountable nouns. When "mood" is used as an uncountable noun, it refers to an abstract concept. When the word is used as a countable noun, it refers to an incident of the abstract idea. You might want to watch this video to see more examples: https://youtu.be/SesnD3ymTAQ

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: +1 No doubt it could be improved, but it's basically the right answer. The context, syntactic, semantic, and pragmatic, while conditioned by nouns and verb, in turn conditions the interpretation of the predicates and arguments, so that, for instance, stative verbs can be used in the progressive construction (even though that's sposta be forbidden), with an interpretation that the state is temporary.

Answer (score 1):

The 'rule'

- *count usages don't take the indefinite article*

is not considered binding by many. CGEL uses the test

- *can a numeral or equivalent ('a dozen ...') be inserted in such a string?*

as the deciding factor.

Here, 'The drink had put him in an amiable mood' cannot be rendered say 'The drink had put them in six amiable moods' and so the usage is deemed 'noncount'. See EA's answer at [a blinding light / blinding sunlight / a blinding sunlight](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227855/a-blinding-light-blinding-sunlight-a-blinding-sunlight) for further discussion.

A count usage of 'mood' is 'I basically have two moods – either *let's do something spontaneous and awesome*, or *let's just lay in bed all day and forget the world exists*.'

Inclusion of a definite article with a non-count usage *can certainly* make a difference to what is being communicated. In the question referred to, an article at *Useful English* contains:

> In formal writing and literary works the article a/an may be used with
> some uncountable abstract nouns to show an unusual or temporary aspect
> of something. The indefinite article here has similar meaning to:
> *such, certain, special, peculiar*....

- Formal / literary style: *The director spoke at the meeting today with an enormous enthusiasm.*
- Standard / everyday style: *The director spoke at the meeting today with great enthusiasm.*

However, certain fixed expressions involving non-count usages *invariably* include the indefinite article. There is no 'standard/everyday' alternative, so the acceptable version perhaps loses impact.

The noun involved does not usually take the plural form.

Many use prepositions peripherally (metaphorically):

- The room was in a mess.
- The rooms were in a mess.
- It must be said that he does have a temper.
- She was in a frenzy.
- He was in a foul mood.
- They were in a foul mood.
- The drink had put him in an amiable mood.
- They went to work with a vengeance.

The example obviously referring to a more general, 'homogenised' referent

- Style allows writers to create mood and evoke feeling in readers.

is obviously better without the indefinite article, especially in a literary commentary as here, though 'a suitable mood' would work if it didn't not pair too well with 'feeling'. Indeed, 'a mood' without modifiers is probably often taken to be equivalent to 'a bad mood': 'My, we *are* in a mood today.'

Comment: Does *Useful English* you mentioned refer to https://usefulenglish.ru/? It seems that this website built by non-native speakers (Russian), so is it reliable?

Comment: [StudyLib](https://studylib.net/doc/7797740/1-the-indefinite-article-a---an-%E2%80%93-one--ones-a---an-we-use...) contains the same material. I obviously endorse the section quoted; it's difficult to find the equivalent analysis in perhaps more prestigious works. // A lot of what is given consists of common examples. There is the caveat 'English doesn't lend itself to inviolable rules', which all works should contain. The only thing I've found with which I don't agree (after a skim reading) in the section on 'articles' is the labelling of nouns rather than usages as 'count'/'non-count'.